# SolrCloud 6 not deleting tlogs on hard commits

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have just implemented SolrCloud 6 with CDCR, and our tlogs are not deleting / rolling off after hard commits.  We currently have 242 tlogs, and they just keep increasing with each days processing.

[solrconfig.xml - source](https://github.com/mmccarthy67/GM/blob/master/solrconfig_source.xml)

[solrconfig.xml - target](https://github.com/mmccarthy67/GM/blob/master/solrconfig_target.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen: https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/

> tlogs are “rolled over” automatically on hard commit (openSearcher true or false). The old one is closed and a new one is opened. Enough tlogs are kept around to contain 100 documents [1], and older tlogs are deleted.

Comment: Yes, we have read this article and others and our configuration is correct according to these, but not working as stated for us.

Comment: Can you sjare your solrconfig.xml with us? Add it to the question if you may.

Comment: I think I figured it out - see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-TransactionLog    You are missing a numRecordsToKeep limit. Could you please add it to your config, restart the service and let's see if the logs start falling off the cliff. If they do, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Working on setting up our test env, to test your fix - will let you know asap.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you guys managed to fix this issue or are you still accumulating tlogs by the dozen?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had been out for the holidays and working through some other priorities.  We are still accumulating them in production.  I have setup our UAT and QA env's to simulate production bc environment and neither configs have numRecordsToKeep in the file, but UAT is not buidling up tlogs.  I did find that in production, this is commented out and is not in UAT.  <updateLog class="solr.CdcrUpdateLog">
            <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
            <!--< int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int> -->
        </updateLog>

Comment: Do you think this could be related?

Comment: Let me dig around. Sry I missed question first time.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks!

Comment: By the looks of it, it should have no bearing on it - related by it only defines the version buckets not how many file to rotate: https://home.apache.org/~ctargett/RefGuidePOC/jekyll-full/updatehandlers-in-solrconfig.html#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-TransactionLog provides a really nice and clear explanation-example combo.

Comment: Thanks!  That was the only difference I could find between our production and test configuration.  I could try implementing your suggestion next production release, but I was hoping to test and confirm this as the issue in our test environment first.

Comment: You can always test my version first. Let me know in any case.